# spring integration JDBC DB-Poller. How to implement Row-Mapper to recieve rows to Task activator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

Please see link :

[Spring Integration: Inbound-channel-adapter update query parameter exception when using RowMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251692/spring-integration-inbound-channel-adapter-update-query-parameter-exception-whe)

I am doing similar config, but not sure how to use row-mapper with splitter.

I am trying to create a db-poller and expecting to receive incoming rows in service-activator using row-mapper, but messages are not reaching there..

Here is my configuration. Please advise.

### My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc" 
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.checkfree.isolutions" />

    <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="invoiceInbound" query="select * from invoice where status = '0'" auto-startup="true"
      channel="invoiceInboundChannel" data-source="dataSource" row-mapper="rowMapper"
      update="update invoice set status = 'PROCESSED' where id in (:id) " max-rows-per-poll="1">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="10000">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" 
                isolation="DEFAULT"
                propagation="REQUIRED" 
                read-only="false" 
                timeout="1000"/>
        </int:poller>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <!-- Add RowMapper tag : row-mapper="rowMapper" -->

    <bean id="rowMapper" class="com.checkfree.isolutions.InvoiceMapper"></bean>

    <int:chain input-channel="invoiceInboundChannel" output-channel="filteredChannel">
            <int:splitter ref="invoiceSplitter" />
    </int:chain>

    <int:channel id="filteredChannel" />    

    <int:service-activator id="taskActivator" input-channel="filteredChannel" ref="taskCreator"  method="processInvoice">
    </int:service-activator>


</beans>
```

### Here is my service activator :

```
@Component("taskCreator")
public class TaskCreator {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TaskCreator.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    InvoiceService invoiceService;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void processInvoice(Object invoiceObj) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("row received.." + invoiceObj.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

I am not able to see print message "row received.." in console.

But in debug rowmapper's is mapRow method is getting called with each invocation.

```
public class InvoiceMapper implements RowMapper {

    @Override
    public Invoice mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
         --
         --
    }
}
```

What I trying to achieve is that my TaskCreator should receive incoming table row in row-mapper (InvoiceMapper) format.

I just corrected my config.

When I switch on debug I can see control going to RowMapper.

Question: I dont know how to use row-mapper with spiltter. can anybody give any example..

Can you please advise. Thanks in advance..

Regards, Shiv

Comment: What does `invoiceSplitter` look like? Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the channels (`preSend, postSend`).

Comment: Gary, Thanks for response. I have corrected my configuration. I can receive messages using invoicesplitter (If I remove row-mapper attribute). when I add row-mapper attribute then processInvoice doesn't get called. In debug mode I can see control going to row-mapper class, but control never goes to TastCreate (service-activator) class.

So If I minus row-mapper entry then My code work very well. But when I add row-mapper which I need for some JDBC specific conversions. then control never goes to service activator class.

Answer (score 0):

You have here two issues:

1. There is no reason to use `<splitter>`, if you expect only one row - `max-rows-per-poll="1"`
2. You have two subscribers for `invoiceInboundChannel` - `<chain>` with `<splitter>` and `<service-activator>`. It works, but not as you expect, because of `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy`

So, maybe your goal is to have `filteredChannel` as an input for `<service-activator>` ?

Comment: Hi Fixed this and used filteredChannel as input for service-activator. My code is working well with splitter. (without using row-mapper). but when I add attribute row-mapper, I dont receive anything in service activator. My question: how to use row-mapper with splitter to receive message in service activator class.

Comment: Well, switch on DEBUG for `org.springframework.integration` category and take a look what's going on with your messages after your row-mapper. Seems for me your row-mapper doesn't return anything, or you do it wrong way. Or there is some expception, but you don't pay attention to it...

Comment: Thanks Artem. Eclipse debug helped to figure out the real exception I was getting. Please see final answer in bottem.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that your 'invoiceInboundChannel' channel is a `DirectChannel` which by definition invokes a single subscriber for each sent Message.

you have configured more than one subscribers (chain and service activator) to that channel. that is why you are facing this issue.

here is the solution. change the `input-channel` of `service-activator` to filteredChannel:

```
<int:service-activator id="taskActivator" input-channel="filteredChannel" ref="taskCreator"  method="processInvoice">
</int:service-activator>
```

hopefully you will receive the splited messages as per your splitter (invoiceSplitter) implementation into your service activator (taskActivator).

Comment: Thanks Ahsan. I fixed. that.(If I remove row-mapper attribute in configuration). But when I add row-mapper attribute then processInvoice doesn't get called. In debug mode I can see control going to row-mapper class, but control never goes to TastCreate (service-activator) class.

So If I minus row-mapper entry then My code work very well. But when I add row-mapper which I need for some JDBC specific conversions. then control never goes to service activator class.
So question is how to use row mapper in this scenerio to receive rows in service-activator class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks my problem was solved.

Issue was not the configuration. But issue is that I in original invoice table got primary key as RAW type (encrypted format) whereas my Invoice Class was showing same field as Long. So while running update I was getting "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got NUMBER". But after debug I could figure out this.

Thanks all for your help.